# How to use base class constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I wanted to define a constructor for a derived class and use the base class constructor which I have defined. I have commented the derived class constructor code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

class person{
    private:
        string name;
        int age;

    public :
        person(int,string); //constructor
 };

class student : public person{ //derived class
    private :
        string teacher;
    public :
        student(string);
};

person :: person(int newage,string newname){

    age = newage;
    name = newname;
    cout <<age << name;
}
/* How do I define the derived class constructor , so that by default
  it calls base class person(int,string) constructor.
student :: student(string newteacher){
    teacher = newteacher;
    cout<<teacher;

}
 */
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   person p(20,"alex");
   student("bob");

    return 0;
}
```

Adding more details:

I want to define my derived class constructor in a way , that I can call base class constructor within my derived class constructor.Right now if I uncomment my derived class constructor I get the following error "no default constructor exists for class person.". Is it possible to do something like:

```
 student object("name",10,"teacher_name")
```

name ,age should be initialized using base class constructor and teacher_name should be initialized using derived class constructor. I am new to C++ , so if something like this is not possible , please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
student :: student(string newteacher) : person(0, newteacher)
{
 // ...
}
```

would be one possibility. You have not explained what exact parameters the base class constructor should receive; adjust as appropriate.